# Hobocopy VSS PST File Backup Script

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup

We have a daily backup with acronis on our server, but for extra sanity I want to copy the .pst files from our file server to another server.

I am using forfiles on 2008 and Hobocopy 1.0 stable, which is similar to robocopy but uses VSS to copy open and locked files. When I run this command I get an "ERROR: Files of type "*.pst" not found."

```
forfiles -p "C:\Data\Mail" /m *.pst -c "cmd /c c:\scripts\hobocopy.exe /incremental /skipdenied /verbosity=4 /r /ignorepattern=backup* echo @file x:\NetworkPSTbackuplocation"
```

If I run it on a specific user's directory I get a different error:

```
forfiles -p "C:\Data\Mail\UserFolder" /m *.pst -c "cmd /c c:\scripts\hobocopy.exe /incremental /skipdenied /verbosity=4 /r /ignorepattern=backup* /simulate @file C:\pstbackup"
```

Output:

```
HoboCopy (c) 2006 Wangdera Corporation. hobocopy@wangdera.com  
Calling CoInitialize  
Starting a incremental copy from C:\Data\Mail\UserFolder\archive2010To2014.pst to  
C:\pstbackup  
Creating DOM document object.
Loading state file from (null).  
Turning off validation  
Failed to load state file from (null). Reason: The parameter is incorrect.  
.  
HoboCopy (c) 2006 Wangdera Corporation. hobocopy@wangdera.com
Calling CoInitialize
Starting a incremental copy from C:\Data\Mail\UserFolder\user.pst to C:\pstback
up
Creating DOM document object.
Loading state file from (null).
Turning off validation
Failed to load state file from (null). Reason: The parameter is incorrect.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "/incremental" parameter you need the "/statefile" one. It is explained here https://github.com/candera/hobocopy

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include a more detailed description of the answer here and provide the link for reference.